# Regular expression that makes a string not contain punctuated/special characters, such as * $ < , > ? ! % [ ] | \?

Tags: python, regex

How do you create a Regular expression that makes a string not contain punctuated/special characters, such as * $ < , > ? ! % [ ] | \?

```
rule = re.compile(r'')
```

Comment: is this list exhaustive? or do you want to match all strings that ONLY contain letters a-zA-Z and maybe digits 0-9?

Comment: A regular expression only matches or fails to match a string. What you want is to remove certain characters, which is not what regular expressions are for, although Python doesn't make this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `regex` or `str.translate` here:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

>>> strs = "fo@#$%sf*&"

>>> re.sub(r'[{}]'.format(punctuation),'',strs)
'fosf'

>>> strs.translate(None,punctuation)
'fosf'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [character classes tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
rule = re.compile(r'^[^*$<,>?!%[]\|\\?]*$')
```

`^`: beggining of string.
`[^ .... ]`: negated  character class - match anything but these characters.
`*`: repeat 0 or more times.
`$`: end of string.